# Angular update template on received data from websocket

Tags: angular, websocket, observable, ng-class

I have a component that listens to a **Websocket** service, this happens on `ngAfterViewInit` as follows:

```
this.store.select(state => state.drifts.drifts)
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$))
  .subscribe(data => 
   this.currentDrifts = data
  )
```

I pass a function in my template to `ngClass` and use the local variable `(this.currentDrifts)` to react accordingly:

```
// Just some object fields, don't mind the naming as it's just for presenting multiple conditions
const servicesDrifts: object = this.currentDrifts[account_id]["service_drifts"];
const accountDrifts: object = this.currentDrifts[account_id]["account_drifts"];

if (Object.keys(servicesDrifts).length) {
  return 'services-drift-spotted';
} else if (Object.keys(accountDrifts).length) {
  return 'accounts-drift-spotted';
} else {
  return 'no-drifts';
}
```

The template (basically it's a table row, I change it's background color):

```
        <tr 
            mat-header-row 
            *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"
        >
            
        </tr>
        <tr
            mat-row
            style="cursor: pointer"
            [ngClass]="row.account_id && detectAccountDrift(row.account_id)"
            (click)="onRowClick(row)"
            *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
        >
        </tr>
```

My question is, how can I ensure that the function inside `ngClass` triggers after the initialization of the component, basically on every message I receive from my Websocket?

I think that I'm looking for something like `useEffect(cb, ['arg1'])` in React, where you can pass a variable to track for changes.

Comment: can you please share the relevant part of your template ?

Comment: @Elmehdi Hey, added the code.

Comment: the `useEffect` in React an be likened to the `ngOnChanges` in angular. The `ngOnChanges` runs everytime the change tracker detects a change in a data-bound property. so with that you could perform checks on the variable you want to track and check if it has changes since the last time you looked up for it

Comment: @Formula12 Thank you very much for your response!
The following question, will my ngClass will be able to trigger itself once that variable changes, or I have to add a flag, something like "updated && function()"

Comment: no you don't trigger `ngOnChanges` . angular automatically triggers it when a data-bound property changes. so just write your code inside it to perform any checks

Comment: @Formula12 I was actually asking when does `ngClass` trigger, tested it and realized it triggers every time my object updates. I don't know why though, I guess it's due to Angular's detection system.
Anyway, thank you very much!